# Multiselect Criteria Query returning NullPointerException in unit tests using mockito framework

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, mockito, criteria

```
@Transactional
    public List<Object[]> findAll() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Object[]> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Object[].class);
        Root<TableA> aRoot = query.from(TableA.class);
        Root<TableB> bRoot = query.from(TableB.class);
        Root<TableC> cRoot = query.from(TableC.class);
        query.multiselect(aRoot.get("type"), cRoot.get("fieldId"), aRoot.get("fieldId"),
                aRoot.get("fieldId"), aRoot.get("name"), aRoot.get("name"),
                aRoot.get("average"), aRoot.get("average"));
        query.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(bRoot.get("fieldId"), cRoot.get("fieldId")),
                criteriaBuilder.in(bRoot.<String>get("type")).value("ABC").value("DFG"),<-----NullPointerException Here
                criteriaBuilder.equal(bRoot.get("type"), aRoot.get("type")));
        query.distinct(true);
       return session.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    }
```

This method has been censored but it works perfectly. My problem is completing the unit test to cover the code so I can push to our repository.

```
    @Before
    @Override
    public void setup() {
        super.setup();
    }

    @InjectMocks
    @Spy
    Dao dao;

    @Mock
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Mock
    Session mockSession;

    @Mock
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder;

    @Mock
    CriteriaQuery<Object> query;

    @Mock
    Root<TableA> mockARoot;

    @Mock
    Root<TableB> mockBRoot;

    @Mock
    Root<TableC> mockCRoot;

    @Mock
    Query<Object> result;

@Test
    public void findAll() {
        Mockito.when(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).thenReturn(mockSession);
        Mockito.when(mockSession.getCriteriaBuilder()).thenReturn(criteriaBuilder);
        Mockito.when(criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Mockito.anyObject())).thenReturn(query);
        Mockito.when(query.from(TableA.class)).thenReturn(mockARoot);
        Mockito.when(query.from(TableB.class)).thenReturn(mockBRoot);
        Mockito.when(query.from(TableC.class)).thenReturn(mockCRoot);
        Mockito.when(mockSession.createQuery(query)).thenReturn(result);
        dao.findAll();
    }
```

I believe the In clause is expecting an expression or predicate. Do I need to mock and pass in other interfaces to get this to work? I would really like to add this style of query construction to our code-base but I cannot complete the junit test. Any assistance would be much appreciated!

When I debug it says the Method "Where()" has not been called

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, people dont use mockito to test the Dao layer.
It should be tested as an integration test.

Regarding mockito, we should mock the layers only where the object other classes are used within the method for example in your code, the variable sessionFactory is an object of other class used in this findAll method in Dao.

We should mock that class, and not the variables which initialized it, within the mehtod (local variables).

P.S: Full error stack trace would be more helpful to address this.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mock all your methods calls... `query.multiselect`, `aRoot.get("fieldId")`... The principle behind mocking is that you are responsible to mock all the needed method calls and define the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test
    public void findAll() {
        when(sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).thenReturn(mockSession);
        when(mockSession.createQuery(anyString())).thenReturn(mockQuery);
        when(mockSession.getCriteriaBuilder()).thenReturn(criteriaBuilder);
        when(criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Mockito.anyObject())).thenReturn(query);
        when(query.from(TableA.class)).thenReturn(mockARoot);
        when(query.from(TableB.class)).thenReturn(mockBRoot);
        when(query.from(TableC.class)).thenReturn(mockCRoot);
        when(mockAreaRoot.get(anyString())).thenReturn(path);
        when(criteriaBuilder.in(path)).thenReturn(in);
        when(in.value(anyString())).thenReturn(in);
        when(mockSession.createQuery(query)).thenReturn(setQuery);
        dao.findAll();
        verify(dao, times(1)).findAll();
    }
```

Not very practical but it gets the job done. Thanks everyone for your suggestions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).